# Inequality of eigenvalues

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I am reading a bit of random matrix theory and came across an inequality which I don't understand. First the hypotheses.

Let Z$^N$ be hermitien matrices of size $N\times N$,$ \lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and $e\in \mathbb{C}$. We denote by $\lambda_{1}^{N}\leq \lambda_{2}^{N}...\leq \lambda_{N}^{N}$ ($\eta_{1}^{N}\leq \eta_{2}^{N}...\leq \eta_{N}^{N}$) the eigenvalues of $Z^{N}$ (resp. $Z^{N}+\lambda ee^*$). By Lidskii's theorem, the eigenvalues $\lambda_{i}$ and $\eta_{i}$ are interlaced;

$$\lambda_{1}^{N}\leq \eta_{2}^{N}\leq \lambda_{3}^{N}...\leq \lambda_{2[\frac{N-1}{2}+1]}^{N}\leq\eta_{2[\frac{N}{2}]}^{N},$$

$$\eta_{1}^{N}\leq \lambda_{2}^{N}\leq \eta_{3}^{N}...\leq \eta_{2[\frac{N-1}{2}+1]}^{N}\leq\lambda_{2[\frac{N}{2}]}^{N}.$$

Now the claim I have problems with.

If $f$ is a bounded increasing function,
$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}f(\lambda_{i}^{N})\leq \displaystyle\sum_{i=2}^{N}f(\eta_{i}^{N})+\frac{1}{N}||f||_{\infty}\leq \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}f(\eta_{i}^{N})+\frac{2}{N}||f||_{\infty}.$$

How do we get the $\frac{1}{N}$ in $\frac{1}{N}||f||_{\infty}$?

Comment: The whole theorem can be found on page 34 here http://www.umpa.ens-lyon.fr/~aguionne/cours.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo: When evaluating the integral there should be a $1/N$ out in front of the sum (see the definition of $L$ on page 28).

Comment: Oh yes. Thank you.